# How to change google map language after first react render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I use https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps.
I need to change my map language by click to button. I can change it only once, for example from ja to ar, but can't back to ja. How can I do that?

```
<MyMapComponent
   key={language}
   googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${key}&language=${this.props.language}`}
   isMarkerShown
   containerElement={
     <div style={{ height: '100%' }} />
   }
   mapElement={
     <div style={{ height: '100%' }} />
   }
   loadingElement={
     <div style={{ height: '100%' }} />
   }
/>
```

Here is example without react http://jsfiddle.net/2AKqM/

PS sorry for my english

Comment: It seems working properly in your jsfiddle.

Comment: @Madhavan.V yep, but I need to use react-google-maps. When I pass new map url, map refreshing but not change language

Answer (score 4):

Apparently it occurs due to a conflict while loading Google Maps API more then *once* on the page. 
You've probably using [`withScriptjs`](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/33c24fa09edac310052e59bd134f8ec0aca20207/src/withScriptjs.jsx) for loading Google Maps API, something like this:

```
export const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => {
  return (
    <GoogleMap googleMapURL={props.googleMapsUrl} defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
      <Marker position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} />
    </GoogleMap>
  )
});
```

The point is, that once the language is provided, the component is getting *re-created* which in turn causes to load Google Maps API again. That scenario is not supported and the following error ussually is getting displayed in console:

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

To prevent such kind of conflicts, the Google Maps API could be cleared

```
window.google.maps = {};
```

before the loading of API for another language.

The below example demonstrates how to handle this scenario, in particular:

- loaded Google Maps API for a current language is stored into a cache
- if Google Maps API has already been loaded per a selected language, it is
  getting re-stored from a cache, otherwise the API is cleared and loaded again

Example:

```js
/*global google*/
import React from "react";
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker
} from "react-google-maps";


const key = "AIzaSyDurZQBXjtSzKeieXwtFeGe-jhZu-HEGQU";

export const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => {
  return (
    <GoogleMap googleMapURL={props.googleMapsUrl} defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
      <Marker position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} />
    </GoogleMap>
  )
});


export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      language: 'en',
      nextLanguage: null,
      googleMapsUrl: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${key}&language=en`,
      cacheMaps: {}
    };
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ nextLanguage: e.target.value });
  }

  changeGoogleMapsLanguage = () => {
    this.setState({ googleMapsUrl: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${key}&language=${this.state.nextLanguage}` });
    this.setState({ language: this.state.nextLanguage });

    let cacheMaps = { ...this.state.cacheMaps }
    cacheMaps[this.state.language] = window.google.maps;
    this.setState({ cacheMaps });

    if (this.state.nextLanguage in cacheMaps) {
      window.google.maps = cacheMaps[this.state.nextLanguage];  //load Maps API from cache
      console.log("Loading from cache..");
    }
    else {
      window.google.maps = {}; //clear Maps components 
    }

  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="language" defaultValue={this.state.language} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
        <button id="localization-button" onClick={this.changeGoogleMapsLanguage.bind(this)} >Change Language</button>
        <MyMapComponent googleMapURL={this.state.googleMapsUrl}
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          key={this.state.googleMapsUrl}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a react hook which is called [gmaps-script-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmaps-script-loader). You can use it as follow:

**App.tsx**

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useScriptLoader } from 'gmaps-script-loader';
import Language from './Language';
import './styles.css';

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  const { loadScript, isMapReady, isReloadOk } = useScriptLoader({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY as string,
    libraries: ['places'],
  });

  const [language, setLanguage] = useState<string>('bahasa');

  useEffect(() => {
    loadScript('id', 'ID');
  }, [loadScript]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current && isMapReady) {
      console.log('map init');
      new google.maps.Map(ref.current, {
        zoom: 12,
        center: { lat: -6.21462, lng: 106.84513 },
      });
    }
  }, [isMapReady]);

  return (
    <>
      {isReloadOk && (
        <Language
          loadScript={loadScript}
          language={language}
          setLanguage={setLanguage}
        />
      )}
      <div ref={ref} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100vh' }} />
    </>
  );
}
```

And the language selector **Language.tsx**

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useEffect } from 'react';

type Lang = { language: string; region: string };

interface Languages {
  [key: string]: Lang;
}

const languages: Languages = {
  bahasa: {
    language: 'id',
    region: 'ID',
  },
  english: {
    language: 'en',
    region: 'GB',
  },
  chinese: {
    language: 'zh',
    region: 'CN',
  },
};

const options = ['bahasa', 'english', 'chinese'];

export default function Language({
  loadScript,
  language,
  setLanguage,
}: {
  loadScript: (language: string, region: string) => void;
  language: string;
  setLanguage: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
}) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (language) {
      const selected = languages[language];
      loadScript(selected.language, selected.region);
    }
  }, [language, loadScript]);

  return (
    <div style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 70, top: 10, zIndex: 50 }}>
      <select value={language} onChange={e => setLanguage(e.target.value)}>
        {options.map(opt => (
          <option value={opt} key={opt}>
            {opt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + opt.slice(1)}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check the demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-yalow-847k8r) and if the **API_KEY** has expired, you can fork the sandbox and replace **REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY** at `.env` file with yours.